# How to check if a '/link/page' already exists on page before adding in JS

Tags: javascript

Before I add a link to a page, I want to check if it already exists anywhere on the page first.

I thought I could do :-

```
if (document.innerHTML.indexOf(link) != -1) {
```

But I get "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

I wonder if there is a way to check if a link already exists on the page.  I would prefer Javascript code as opposed to JQuery please.

Your help, much appreciated.

Comment: `document.querySelector('a[href="/link/page"]')`

Comment: Awesome, shame you didn't give it as an answer so that I can mark as answer and slightly expand on it.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.body.textContent.search("link")
```

Use body.textContent instead of innerHTML

If you get -1 as result then it means it does not exists else it will probably give you the position of the match.

Refer : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp 
and https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp